# Scene Builder , how to pair ComboBoxs selection

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, scenebuilder

Using jdk1.7.0_80.jdk: 
I have 2 ComboBoxes; I want to select a value from the mainComboBox and subCombobox gets loaded automatically based on the value selected from the mainComboBox. and with its unique  set of choices in the subComboBox: My initialization works as seen in the screenshot below. 
[image]

Now my issue is when I change the value of the mainComboBox. when I do that nothing gets preselected/displayed in the subComoboBox. I am using comboBoxChoice to load the different options available in the ObservableList. But for some odd reason it's not kicking in.

[image]

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    ObservableList<String> mainList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Main-1","Main-2","Main-3");
     ObservableList<String> main1SubList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Main1-Sub1","Main1-Sub2","Main1-Sub3");
     ObservableList<String> main2SubList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Main2-Sub1","Main2-Sub2","Main2-Sub3");
     ObservableList<String> main3SubList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Main3-Sub1","Main3-Sub2","Main3-Sub3");


    @FXML
    private ComboBox mainComboBox, subComboBox;


   @Override 
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        mainComboBox.setValue("Main-1");
        mainComboBox.setItems(mainList);

        subComboBox.setValue("Main1-Sub1");
       subComboBox.setItems(main1SubList);
     }    

    @FXML
    private void comboBoxChoice() {
        if (mainComboBox.getValue().equals("Main-1") ) {
            subComboBox.setValue("Main1-Sub1");
            subComboBox.setItems(main1SubList);
        }
        if (mainComboBox.getValue().equals("Main-2") ) {
            subComboBox.setValue("Main2-Sub1");
            subComboBox.setItems(main2SubList);
        }
        if (mainComboBox.getValue().equals("Main-3") ) {
            subComboBox.setValue("Main3-Sub1");
            subComboBox.setItems(main3SubList);
        }

    }
}
```

FXML file:

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication18.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" />
      <ComboBox fx:id="mainComboBox" layoutX="103.0" layoutY="136.0" onAction="#comboBoxChoice" prefWidth="150.0" />
      <ComboBox fx:id="subComboBox" layoutX="103.0" layoutY="162.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: This works as expected for me. What JDK version are you using? Maybe try switching the calls to `setItems()` and `setValue()`.

Comment: jdk1.7.0_80.jdk. Swapping the setItems() and setValue() worked. Please  submit this as the correct answer to mark it for you. Thanks again. I am not sure why it didn't work the other way around for me but it worked for you.

Comment: Your JDK is very out of date. It's likely an old bug that has since been fixed. Added an answer; glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me on JDK 1.8.0_66. It may be that this is an old bug that has since been fixed.

I would recommend switching the order of `setItems()` and `setValue()`; it's likely that replacing all the items removes the old selected item, even if it is in the "new" list.

I.e.

```
@FXML
private void comboBoxChoice() {
    if (mainComboBox.getValue().equals("Main-1") ) {
        subComboBox.setItems(main1SubList);
        subComboBox.setValue("Main1-Sub1");
    }
    if (mainComboBox.getValue().equals("Main-2") ) {
        subComboBox.setItems(main2SubList);
        subComboBox.setValue("Main2-Sub1");
    }
    if (mainComboBox.getValue().equals("Main-3") ) {
        subComboBox.setItems(main3SubList);
        subComboBox.setValue("Main3-Sub1");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I am getting (URL url, ResourceBundle rb) rb null pointer when I try to move from one scene to the other. my combobox has value. so I am not sure why i am getting that null pointer.